# ¿Cómo seleccionar un elemento HTML desde un componente.ts en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Necesito obtener unos datos de la única etiqueta `<img>` que está en mi componente utilizando un `getElementsByTagName`.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mensaje-formulario',
  templateUrl: './mensaje-formulario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mensaje-formulario.component.css']
})
export class MensajeFormularioComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
    let src = document.getElementsByTagname('img');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let src = getElementsByTagname('img');
  }

}
```

Estoy intentando con `document.getElementsByTagname` y con `getElementsByTagname` porque mi editor de texto me indica que esa propiedad no existe en el tipo 'Document'.

La consola me da el siguiente error:

```
document.getElementsByTagname is not a function
    at MensajeFormularioComponent.push../src/app/componentes/mensaje-formulario/mensaje-formulario.component.ts.MensajeFormularioComponent.ngAfterViewInit
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener un elemento utilizando una propiedad similar?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías asignar un `#nombre` al elemento y de esta forma recibes toda la información de ese elemento en tu componente

Answer (score 2):

si es solamente de una etiqueta especifica la forma correcta es crear un ViewChild

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img #imgElement src="www.example.com">
</div>
```

Componente: 
Aqui utilizamos el ViewChild para acceder a la referencia del elemento HTML (tipo ElementRef)

```
// importar el decorador de angular/core
Import (ViewChild) from '@angular/core'

// Uso del decorador @ViewChild('aqui va lo que hayas definido en el html con el #') variable: ElementRef
@ViewChild('imgElement') imgElement: ElementRef;

algunaFuncion(){
    // Acceder al nativeElement del child
    console.log(imgElement.nativeElement);
}
```